# Disable Keybindings in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, key-bindings

I have a menu in my WPF app. Some menu items can also be called by shortcut. But I want some shortcuts not always be active.

I tried various code but got stuck. This is my current approach:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static views:MainWindow.SavePartCommand}"
                    Executed="SavePartExecuted"
                    CanExecute="SavePartCanExecute"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{x:Static views:MainWindow.SavePartCommand}" 
                Key="S" Modifiers="Ctrl" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

But `SavePartCommand` is not recognized and if I define that in my Code-Behind I don't know how to link that static command to my actual MVVM Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by completely defining the keybinding in my code-behind like this

```
this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(((MainViewModel) this.DataContext).  
                           SavePartCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you already got around it. Good.

Still, one way to do this w/o having any code-behind code would be to modify the static command's `CanExecute` logic from your viewmodel.

Let's say you have a `MainWindow`, it's data context as `MainViewModel` and your menu related commands in static `Commands` class. Then consider the following XAML for MainWindow.

```
// xmlns:app="clr-namespace:<app_namespace>"
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static app:Commands.SavePartCommand}" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="app:Commands.SavePartCommand" Key="S" Modifiers="Ctrl" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

This is basically the same code you posted but no event handlers specified. In MainViewModel you simply instruct your `SavePartsCommand` to not be available.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Commands.ToggleCanExecuteSavePartsCommand = true;
    }
}
```

And the actual (dummy) command could then look like the following.

```
public static class Commands
{
    private static RelayCommand _savePartsCommand;

    public static ICommand SavePartCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _savePartsCommand ?? 
                (_savePartsCommand = new RelayCommand(() => 
                    Console.WriteLine(@"Save"), CanExecuteSavePartsCommand));
        }
    }

    public static bool ToggleCanExecuteSavePartsCommand { get; set; }

    private static bool CanExecuteSavePartsCommand()
    {
        return ToggleCanExecuteSavePartsCommand;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.